# #1111 - Invalid use of group function in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1111

I have a table M_DAILY with fields

```
PS_DATE date,
tp int,
ep int,
mp int,
```

and have a working version of a user defined `function nvl(x,y)` which returns x if not null and y if x is null

My MySQL query is-

```
select sum(avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(tp,0) else 0 end))tp, sum(avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(ep,0) else 0 end)) ep, sum(avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(mp,0) else 0 end)) mp
from M_DAILY
where PS_DATE >= date ('2005-01-01') and PS_DATE <= date ('2005-12-31')
group by PS_DATE;
```

I get the following error

> ```
> #1111 - Invalid use of group function in mysql
> ```

Please help.

Comment: `PS_DATE BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31'`

Comment: no effect, same error

Comment: Update your question with your new information - if you still need help with some aspect of this

Answer (score 1):

> SUM(), COUNT(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), etc. are aggregate functions that
>   requires you to specify a GROUP BY, unless you're using them on every
>   column in your SELECT-list.

Remove **Group By** Clause

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(tp),SUM(ep),SUM(mp) FROM
(
    SELECT Avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(tp,0) else 0 end) tp,   
           Avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(ep,0) else 0 end) ep, 
           Avg(case date_format(PS_DATE,'%Y') when '2005' then nvl(mp,0) else 0 end) mp   
    FROM M_DAILY 
    WHERE PS_DATE >= date ('2005-01-01') and PS_DATE <= date ('2005-12-31');
) As T
```

Comment: I tried both the options suggested by you,but no effect, it still produces the same error

Comment: @tanzeem Try With `Group By tp,ep,mp`

Comment: No effect again. Does it have something to do with the having clause

Comment: i checked and found that sum(avg(...)) cant be used together.when i used avg(..) i get the values. It seems that i have to use the sum separately

Comment: oh then Try above my new solution..@tanzeem